# User not created in MySQL when using docker-compose

Tags: mysql, docker-compose, docker-volume

This is what I see when I am in the container created by docker-compose:

```
mysql> SELECT user FROM mysql.user;
+------+
| user |
+------+
| root |
+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

root@541e4d686184:/# echo $MYSQL_USER
dbuser
```

So `dbuser` is not present in the users table even though the `$MYSQL_USER` is set properly .

In `docker-compose.yml` I have this:

```
version: '2'
services:
  db:
    image: mysql:latest
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: mydb
      MYSQL_USER: dbuser
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: userpass
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
    ports:
      - "3306"
    volumes:
      - ./docker-entrypoint-initdb.d:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
      - my-datavolume:/var/lib/mysql
volumes:
  my-datavolume:
```

I expected `dbuser` to be created automatically, but that didn't happen.

I also have a `sql` file to create my database and tables if they don't already exist, but right now tomcat can't connect to my database.

Same symptoms as this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37459031/connecting-to-a-docker-compose-mysql-container-denies-access-but-docker-running), but I am already using a dictionary for my usernames/passwords.

**UPDATE:**

I am getting close. When inside container I manually did:

```
/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/create_users.sh
```

Then the user was created inside `MySQL` table and I was able to deploy my application to my `tomcat` server and I didn't get an error about `dbuser` being denied access.

So, why did I have to run this command myself, it should be run by docker-compose, according to the [mysql docker docs](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/) under *Initializing a fresh instance*.

Comment: Did you check the output of `docker logs`? The mysql logs? Did you consider user permissions issues? Did you consider using the mysql client for running your sql script? (e.g. `/usr/bin/mysql < /path/to/script.sql`)

Comment: @mlg - I did see that it tried to create this new user, but the root user password worked. I can add the user manually, through the Dockerfile, I just didn't want to do that if possible.

Comment: sql scripts are good for more than creating users; it might end up being a good thing having a startup script. Do you foresee needing some extra startup actions? It might save you dealing with this altogether.

Comment: @mig - No, I don't see any other use, but at the moment it works this way.  I can save the docker image with the database set up and then just deploy that so everything stays correct.  I don't like this option, but it appears it may be my best one.

Comment: I'm having the same problem here. It used to work great before, and now, this. I don't know why.

Comment: Same issue for me right now. User is not created in the DB.

Comment: For me this issue was caused by using a blank password. Setting the password to a non empty string fixed it. What threw me off was `MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD` but this only applies to the root user not the `MYSQL_USER`

There was a message in the logs `MYSQL_USER specified, but missing MYSQL_PASSWORD; MYSQL_USER will not be created`

Answer (score 30):

How about:

```
docker-compose down -v
```

From [the documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/down/):

> `-v` - Remove volumes declared in the volumes section of the Compose file.

Your database has been already created inside a volume, so any changes of initial settings in `docker-compose.yml` won't be reflected.

In case you want to remove just a single volume, you may use `docker volume ls` to list all existing volumes and then `docker volume rm <VOLUME NAME>` to remove it.

**Note:** [Bind mounts](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/) are not removed with the `-v` flag, so in case you are using them instead of volumes, you'll have to manually delete folders containing `MySQL` data. In `docker-compose` bind mounts are created whenever you provide a source path in your `volumes` section (eg. `/my-path:/var/lib/mysql`).

Comment: Great suggestion. Saved my day! Use docker-compose down -v
docker-compose up --build to rebuild image

Comment: **Note**: Bind mounts aren't removed with the `-v` flag, so you'll have to manually delete the mount's contents. This caught me off guard for far longer than I'd like to admit..

Comment: After hours of struggle, I'm glad I came across your answer! Many thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Worked for me : **stop docker and remove manually all the folder containing MySQL data** from previous builds.

Also : don't forget to add a `MYSQL_DATABASE` environment var or it won't create the user you specified.

Answer (score 1):

[Github issue](https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/issues/180)

> Important to note that the image entrypoint script will never make
>   changes to an existing database. If you mount an existing data
>   directory into var/lib/mysql, options like MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD will
>   have no effect

Comment: How do you mount a volume for persistent storage then?...

Answer (score 0):

I met the same issue, you may try to remove everything under 'my-datavolume' because the environment works only in the initial stage that means there should not any data in '/var/lib/mysql'. This approach worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is:

```
docker-compose down
docker volume ls
docker volume rm <volume-name>
docker-compose up -d
```

In the newly created volume, my user was there.

Answer (score 0):

after my testing,

1. create init.sql and links to /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
2. docker-compose down
   docker volume ls
   docker volume rm 
   docker-compose up -d

then everythi is ok