# How to use MySQL and Flask-PonyORM App with docker-compose?

Tags: python-3.x, flask, docker-compose, dockerfile, ponyorm

I'm having a trouble on how to configure my application to integrate Flask, PonyORM, and MySQL using docker and docker-compose.

This is my `.yml` file:

```
version: '3.1'
services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: kofre.db

  adminer:
    image: adminer
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:8080

  python:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - .:/kofre-app
    ports:
      - 5000:5000
    depends_on:
      - mysql
```

This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3
ENV PYTHONBUFFERED 1

RUN mkdir /kofre-app

WORKDIR /kofre-app

COPY setup.py /kofre-app/
RUN python setup.py install

COPY . /kofre-app/

CMD [ "python", "./run.py" ]
```

and this is a part of my Pony initialization script:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object('config')

db = Database()
db.bind(provider = 'mysql', host = 'mysql', user = 'root', passwd = 'root', db = 'kofre.db')
```

My problems:

1. Sometimes when I run the command `docker-compose up` I'm getting the message: "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'mysql' (timed out)". Is it a proble with PonyORM? Should I use another framework?
2. And sometimes, the `mysql` service seems to lock the prompt and nothing happens after that.

Could someone help me with this problems? I'd appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of search and tries, I finally got it working. My problem was the incorrect sintax in my `docker-compose.yml` in the section of the `environment` of the mysql container.

Now, my newer `docker-compose.yml` looks like this:

```
version: '3'
services:
  python:
    build: .
    container_name: python
    volumes:
      - .:/kofre-app
    ports:
      - 5000:5000
    links:
      - mysql

  adminer:
    image: adminer
    container_name: adminer
    ports:
      - 8000:8080
    links:
      - mysql

  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.6
    container_name: mysql
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=kofre.db
      - MYSQL_USER=root
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=root
```

The answer to this problem I found here in [this another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41282871/4027692)