# MySQL Not Binding to Correct Port When Running docker-compose in CloudBuild

Tags: docker-compose, continuous-integration, google-cloud-build

I am working on a CloudBuild script that needs to instantiate a local DB for testing of a backend service. I am using `docker/compose:1.25.3` for this purpose. The script works locally but when running on CloudBuild the service is unable to connect to the database. The relevant scripts can be observed below:

**docker-compose.test.yml**

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  app:
    image: gcr.io/${PROJECT_ID}/<REDACTED>/test:${SHORT_SHA}
    command: ["bundle", "exec", "rails", "t"]
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    depends_on:
      - db      
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7.24
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=true
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=sales_test
      - MYSQL_HOST=0.0.0.0
      - MYSQL_TCP_PORT=3306

networks:
  default:
      external:
          name: cloudbuild
```

**cloudbuild.yaml**

```
steps:
  # Run Tests
  - name: 'docker/compose:1.25.3'
    id: test
    args: ['-f', 'docker-compose.test.yml', 'up', '--exit-code-from', 'app']
    env:
      - 'PROJECT_ID=$PROJECT_ID'
      - 'SHORT_SHA=$SHORT_SHA'
```

The error log (with minor redactions) can be seen below:

```
Pulling image: docker/compose:1.25.3
1.25.3: Pulling from docker/compose
89d9c30c1d48: Already exists
8c7adae20efb: Pulling fs layer
c8bcdc0a450b: Pulling fs layer
cee865d72b79: Pulling fs layer
8c7adae20efb: Verifying Checksum
8c7adae20efb: Download complete
8c7adae20efb: Pull complete
cee865d72b79: Verifying Checksum
cee865d72b79: Download complete
c8bcdc0a450b: Verifying Checksum
c8bcdc0a450b: Download complete
c8bcdc0a450b: Pull complete
cee865d72b79: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:3ab5ae464a8a428085729d6a0f2ab7a5ccc5524f6ca8649855c7d21fb86148cd
Status: Downloaded newer image for docker/compose:1.25.3
docker.io/docker/compose:1.25.3
using --exit-code-from implies --abort-on-container-exit
Pulling db (mysql:5.7.24)...
5.7.24: Pulling from library/mysql
Digest: sha256:bf17a7109057494c45fba5aab7fc805ca00ac1eef638dfdd42b38d5a7190c9bb
Status: Downloaded newer image for mysql:5.7.24
Pulling app (gcr.io/<REDACTED>)...
e98c184: Pulling from <REDACTED>
Digest: sha256:55f6679af82d7ca5ccac5a2d2aefe0b1c75e4d65b49cd6c6a768c074dfafc483
Status: Downloaded newer image for gcr.io/<REDACTED>
Creating workspace_db_1 ... 

Attaching to workspace_db_1, workspace_app_1
db_1   | Initializing database
db_1   | 2020-02-09T16:53:45.954586Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
db_1   | 2020-02-09T16:53:47.683244Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: New log files created, LSN=45790
db_1   | 2020-02-09T16:53:47.892451Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Creating foreign key constraint system tables.
db_1   | 2020-02-09T16:53:47.953412Z 0 [Warning] No existing UUID has been found, so we assume that this is the first time that this server has been started. Generating a new UUID: bdad19cb-4b5c-11ea-a027-0242c0a80a03.
db_1   | 2020-02-09T16:53:47.957113Z 0 [Warning] Gtid table is not ready to be used. Table 'mysql.gtid_executed' cannot be opened.
db_1   | 2020-02-09T16:53:47.958298Z 1 [Warning] root@localhost is created with an empty password ! Please consider switching off the --initialize-insecure option.
db_1   | 2020-02-09T16:53:48.693564Z 1 [Warning] 'user' entry 'root@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
db_1   | 2020-02-09T16:53:48.694594Z 1 [Warning] 'user' entry 'mysql.session@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
db_1   | 2020-02-09T16:53:48.695129Z 1 [Warning] 'user' entry 'mysql.sys@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
db_1   | 2020-02-09T16:53:48.695592Z 1 [Warning] 'db' entry 'performance_schema mysql.session@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
db_1   | 2020-02-09T16:53:48.695985Z 1 [Warning] 'db' entry 'sys mysql.sys@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
db_1   | 2020-02-09T16:53:48.696090Z 1 [Warning] 'proxies_priv' entry '@ root@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
db_1   | 2020-02-09T16:53:48.696300Z 1 [Warning] 'tables_priv' entry 'user mysql.session@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
db_1   | 2020-02-09T16:53:48.696425Z 1 [Warning] 'tables_priv' entry 'sys_config mysql.sys@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
db_1   | Database initialized
db_1   | Initializing certificates
db_1   | Generating a RSA private key
db_1   | .............................................+++++
db_1   | .+++++
db_1   | unable to write 'random state'
db_1   | writing new private key to 'ca-key.pem'
db_1   | -----
db_1   | Generating a RSA private key
db_1   | .........................+++++
db_1   | ................................+++++
db_1   | unable to write 'random state'
db_1   | writing new private key to 'server-key.pem'
db_1   | -----
db_1   | Generating a RSA private key
db_1   | ........................................................+++++
db_1   | .......................................................................................................+++++
db_1   | unable to write 'random state'
db_1   | writing new private key to 'client-key.pem'
db_1   | -----
db_1   | Certificates initialized
db_1   | MySQL init process in progress...
db_1   | 2020-02-09T16:53:52.331939Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
db_1   | 2020-02-09T16:53:52.338264Z 0 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 5.7.24) starting as process 88 ...
db_1   | 2020-02-09T16:53:52.342658Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: PUNCH HOLE support available
db_1   | 2020-02-09T16:53:52.345876Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
db_1   | 2020-02-09T16:53:52.346533Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
db_1   | 2020-02-09T16:53:52.347011Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier
db_1   | 2020-02-09T16:53:52.347439Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
db_1   | 2020-02-09T16:53:52.347864Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
db_1   | 2020-02-09T16:53:52.348711Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
db_1   | 2020-02-09T16:53:52.349446Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
db_1   | 2020-02-09T16:53:52.352053Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
db_1   | 2020-02-09T16:53:52.374298Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
db_1   | 2020-02-09T16:53:52.377886Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. See the man page of setpriority().
db_1   | 2020-02-09T16:53:52.389720Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
db_1   | 2020-02-09T16:53:52.406894Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
db_1   | 2020-02-09T16:53:52.409937Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
db_1   | 2020-02-09T16:53:52.616442Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
db_1   | 2020-02-09T16:53:52.617610Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 96 redo rollback segment(s) found. 96 redo rollback segment(s) are active.
db_1   | 2020-02-09T16:53:52.618823Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 32 non-redo rollback segment(s) are active.
db_1   | 2020-02-09T16:53:52.619566Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
db_1   | 2020-02-09T16:53:52.670260Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 5.7.24 started; log sequence number 2591440
db_1   | 2020-02-09T16:53:52.671455Z 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
db_1   | 2020-02-09T16:53:52.682070Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
db_1   | 2020-02-09T16:53:52.684590Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 200209 16:53:52
db_1   | 2020-02-09T16:53:52.690301Z 0 [Note] Found ca.pem, server-cert.pem and server-key.pem in data directory. Trying to enable SSL support using them.
db_1   | 2020-02-09T16:53:52.691413Z 0 [Warning] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
db_1   | 2020-02-09T16:53:52.696830Z 0 [Warning] Insecure configuration for --pid-file: Location '/var/run/mysqld' in the path is accessible to all OS users. Consider choosing a different directory.
db_1   | 2020-02-09T16:53:52.698713Z 0 [Warning] 'user' entry 'root@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
db_1   | 2020-02-09T16:53:52.699389Z 0 [Warning] 'user' entry 'mysql.session@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
db_1   | 2020-02-09T16:53:52.699887Z 0 [Warning] 'user' entry 'mysql.sys@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
db_1   | 2020-02-09T16:53:52.700362Z 0 [Warning] 'db' entry 'performance_schema mysql.session@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
db_1   | 2020-02-09T16:53:52.700817Z 0 [Warning] 'db' entry 'sys mysql.sys@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
db_1   | 2020-02-09T16:53:52.701498Z 0 [Warning] 'proxies_priv' entry '@ root@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
db_1   | 2020-02-09T16:53:52.703369Z 0 [Warning] 'tables_priv' entry 'user mysql.session@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
db_1   | 2020-02-09T16:53:52.703956Z 0 [Warning] 'tables_priv' entry 'sys_config mysql.sys@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
db_1   | 2020-02-09T16:53:52.713772Z 0 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
db_1   | 2020-02-09T16:53:52.721653Z 0 [Note] mysqld: ready for connections.
db_1   | Version: '5.7.24'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 0  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
db_1   | Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/iso3166.tab' as time zone. Skipping it.
db_1   | Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/leap-seconds.list' as time zone. Skipping it.
db_1   | Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/zone.tab' as time zone. Skipping it.
db_1   | Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/zone1970.tab' as time zone. Skipping it.
db_1   | 2020-02-09T16:53:56.959302Z 4 [Warning] 'user' entry 'root@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
db_1   | 2020-02-09T16:53:56.960220Z 4 [Warning] 'user' entry 'mysql.session@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
db_1   | 2020-02-09T16:53:56.960744Z 4 [Warning] 'user' entry 'mysql.sys@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
db_1   | 2020-02-09T16:53:56.961208Z 4 [Warning] 'db' entry 'performance_schema mysql.session@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
db_1   | 2020-02-09T16:53:56.961636Z 4 [Warning] 'db' entry 'sys mysql.sys@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
db_1   | 2020-02-09T16:53:56.962216Z 4 [Warning] 'proxies_priv' entry '@ root@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
db_1   | 2020-02-09T16:53:56.962711Z 4 [Warning] 'tables_priv' entry 'user mysql.session@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
db_1   | 2020-02-09T16:53:56.963322Z 4 [Warning] 'tables_priv' entry 'sys_config mysql.sys@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
db_1   | 
db_1   | 2020-02-09T16:53:56.981051Z 0 [Note] Giving 0 client threads a chance to die gracefully
db_1   | 2020-02-09T16:53:56.981952Z 0 [Note] Shutting down slave threads
db_1   | 2020-02-09T16:53:56.982615Z 0 [Note] Forcefully disconnecting 0 remaining clients
db_1   | 2020-02-09T16:53:56.983096Z 0 [Note] Event Scheduler: Purging the queue. 0 events
db_1   | 2020-02-09T16:53:56.983631Z 0 [Note] Binlog end
db_1   | 2020-02-09T16:53:56.984775Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'ngram'
db_1   | 2020-02-09T16:53:56.985319Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'partition'
db_1   | 2020-02-09T16:53:56.985783Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'BLACKHOLE'
db_1   | 2020-02-09T16:53:56.986270Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'ARCHIVE'
db_1   | 2020-02-09T16:53:56.986693Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA'
db_1   | 2020-02-09T16:53:56.987126Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MRG_MYISAM'
db_1   | 2020-02-09T16:53:56.987689Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MyISAM'
db_1   | 2020-02-09T16:53:56.989856Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_VIRTUAL'
db_1   | 2020-02-09T16:53:56.990394Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_DATAFILES'
db_1   | 2020-02-09T16:53:56.990818Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESPACES'
db_1   | 2020-02-09T16:53:56.991482Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN_COLS'
db_1   | 2020-02-09T16:53:56.991930Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN'
db_1   | 2020-02-09T16:53:56.992046Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FIELDS'
db_1   | 2020-02-09T16:53:56.992159Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_COLUMNS'
db_1   | 2020-02-09T16:53:56.992229Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_INDEXES'
db_1   | 2020-02-09T16:53:56.992287Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESTATS'
db_1   | 2020-02-09T16:53:56.992387Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLES'
db_1   | 2020-02-09T16:53:56.992455Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_TABLE'
db_1   | 2020-02-09T16:53:56.992513Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_CACHE'
db_1   | 2020-02-09T16:53:56.992577Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_CONFIG'
db_1   | 2020-02-09T16:53:56.992685Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_BEING_DELETED'
db_1   | 2020-02-09T16:53:56.992755Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DELETED'
db_1   | 2020-02-09T16:53:56.992811Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DEFAULT_STOPWORD'
db_1   | 2020-02-09T16:53:56.992874Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_METRICS'
db_1   | 2020-02-09T16:53:56.992939Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_TEMP_TABLE_INFO'
db_1   | 2020-02-09T16:53:56.993063Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_POOL_STATS'
db_1   | 2020-02-09T16:53:56.993134Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE_LRU'
db_1   | 2020-02-09T16:53:56.993204Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE'
db_1   | 2020-02-09T16:53:56.993274Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX_RESET'
db_1   | 2020-02-09T16:53:56.993340Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX'
db_1   | 2020-02-09T16:53:56.993408Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM_RESET'
db_1   | 2020-02-09T16:53:56.993465Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM'
db_1   | 2020-02-09T16:53:56.993534Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_RESET'
db_1   | 2020-02-09T16:53:56.993644Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP'
db_1   | 2020-02-09T16:53:56.993712Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCK_WAITS'
db_1   | 2020-02-09T16:53:56.993768Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCKS'
db_1   | 2020-02-09T16:53:56.993902Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_TRX'
db_1   | 2020-02-09T16:53:56.993974Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'InnoDB'
db_1   | 2020-02-09T16:53:56.997425Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: FTS optimize thread exiting.
db_1   | 2020-02-09T16:53:56.997740Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
app_1  | DEPRECATION WARNING: ActiveSupport.halt_callback_chains_on_return_false= is deprecated and will be removed in Rails 5.2. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/initializers/new_framework_defaults.rb:25)
app_1  | /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/mysql2-0.4.10/lib/mysql2/client.rb:89:in `connect': Can't connect to MySQL server on 'db' (115) (Mysql2::Error)
app_1  |    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/mysql2-0.4.10/lib/mysql2/client.rb:89:in `initialize'
app_1  |    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:21:in `new'
app_1  |    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:21:in `mysql2_connection'
app_1  |    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:759:in `new_connection'
app_1  |    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:803:in `checkout_new_connection'
app_1  |    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:782:in `try_to_checkout_new_connection'
app_1  |    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:743:in `acquire_connection'
app_1  |    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:500:in `checkout'
app_1  |    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:374:in `connection'
app_1  |    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:931:in `retrieve_connection'
app_1  |    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.2/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:116:in `retrieve_connection'
app_1  |    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.2/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:88:in `connection'
app_1  |    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.2/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:331:in `table_exists?'
app_1  |    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/bundler/gems/spree-5ff46f2f5990/core/app/models/spree/preferences/store.rb:89:in `should_persist?'
app_1  |    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/bundler/gems/spree-5ff46f2f5990/core/app/models/spree/preferences/store.rb:74:in `persist'
app_1  |    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/bundler/gems/spree-5ff46f2f5990/core/app/models/spree/preferences/store.rb:21:in `set'
app_1  |    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/bundler/gems/spree-5ff46f2f5990/core/app/models/spree/preferences/scoped_store.rb:17:in `[]='
app_1  |    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/bundler/gems/spree-5ff46f2f5990/core/app/models/spree/preferences/preferable_class_methods.rb:20:in `block in preference'
app_1  |    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/bundler/gems/spree-5ff46f2f5990/core/app/models/spree/preferences/preferable.rb:48:in `set_preference'
app_1  |    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/bundler/gems/spree-5ff46f2f5990/core/app/models/spree/preferences/configuration.rb:61:in `method_missing'
app_1  |    from /app/config/initializers/spree.rb:13:in `block in <top (required)>'
app_1  |    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/bundler/gems/spree-5ff46f2f5990/core/lib/spree/core.rb:59:in `config'
app_1  |    from /app/config/initializers/spree.rb:12:in `<top (required)>'
app_1  |    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:286:in `load'
app_1  |    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:286:in `block in load'
app_1  |    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:258:in `load_dependency'
app_1  |    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:286:in `load'
app_1  |    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:655:in `block in load_config_initializer'
app_1  |    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.2/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:168:in `instrument'
app_1  |    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:654:in `load_config_initializer'
app_1  |    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:612:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
app_1  |    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:611:in `each'
app_1  |    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:611:in `block in <class:Engine>'
app_1  |    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
app_1  |    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
app_1  |    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:59:in `block in run_initializers'
app_1  |    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
app_1  |    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
app_1  |    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:422:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
app_1  |    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
app_1  |    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:421:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
app_1  |    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:48:in `each'
app_1  |    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:48:in `tsort_each_child'
app_1  |    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:415:in `call'
app_1  |    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:415:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
app_1  |    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
app_1  |    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
app_1  |    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
app_1  |    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
app_1  |    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
app_1  |    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
app_1  |    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:58:in `run_initializers'
app_1  |    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.2/lib/rails/application.rb:353:in `initialize!'
app_1  |    from /app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
app_1  |    from /app/test/test_helper.rb:4:in `require'
app_1  |    from /app/test/test_helper.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
app_1  |    from /app/test/controllers/admin/login_controller_test.rb:1:in `require'
app_1  |    from /app/test/controllers/admin/login_controller_test.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
app_1  |    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.2/lib/rails/test_unit/test_requirer.rb:14:in `require'
app_1  |    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.2/lib/rails/test_unit/test_requirer.rb:14:in `block in require_files'
app_1  |    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.2/lib/rails/test_unit/test_requirer.rb:13:in `each'
app_1  |    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.2/lib/rails/test_unit/test_requirer.rb:13:in `require_files'
app_1  |    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.2/lib/rails/test_unit/minitest_plugin.rb:94:in `plugin_rails_init'
app_1  |    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/minitest-5.11.3/lib/minitest.rb:81:in `block in init_plugins'
app_1  |    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/minitest-5.11.3/lib/minitest.rb:79:in `each'
app_1  |    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/minitest-5.11.3/lib/minitest.rb:79:in `init_plugins'
app_1  |    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/minitest-5.11.3/lib/minitest.rb:130:in `run'
app_1  |    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.2/lib/rails/test_unit/minitest_plugin.rb:77:in `run'
app_1  |    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/minitest-5.11.3/lib/minitest.rb:63:in `block in autorun'
db_1   | 2020-02-09T16:53:57.100166Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s) to /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
db_1   | 2020-02-09T16:53:57.100642Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) dump completed at 200209 16:53:57
app_1  | Coverage report generated for MiniTest to /app/coverage. 278 / 716 LOC (38.83%) covered.
workspace_app_1 exited with code 1

Aborting on container exit...
```

The log line that reads `Version: '5.7.24'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 0  MySQL Community Server (GPL)` has called my attention since the port is set to 0 despite me setting it to 3306 (and 3306 being the default). When running locally, the port is correctly set to 3306. Am I misunderstanding how the networking works inside CloudBuild? Is using docker-compose the recommended method to accomplish this?

Comment: Have you tried specifying the port using `ports` variable inside `db`? Check out this [Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37459031/connecting-to-a-docker-compose-mysql-container-denies-access-but-docker-running), which will give you an idea. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: @sllopis Tried it just now and the erroneous behavior continues.

Comment: That's interesting. I was researching around and came across the following [GitHub thread](https://github.com/standardfile/ruby-server/issues/68) that talks about changing `MYSQL_HOST=0.0.0.0` to `MYSQL_HOST=db`. It has worked for some people.

Comment: Hi @Paulo, did issue is solved? If not, could you add more information?

Comment: @Juancki I believe I figured out the problem! Still workin on a solution though. The MySQL container sometimes restarts after setting up the DB (seems to be part of its normal process). However, its status (which is used by the depends_on) is set before restarting. Which means that the app may try to connect to the DB while it is restarting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was related to a race condition due to the docker-compose `depends_on` attribute waiting only for a container (in this case `db`) to be ready but having no guarantee on the actual code in the container (in this case a MySQL instance) running.

The solution was to add the script `wait-for-mysql.sh` shown below:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
# wait-for-mysql.sh

set -e

host="$1"
shift
cmd="$@"

until mysql -h "db" -u "root" --connect_timeout 1 -e "\q"; do
  >&2 echo "MySQL is unavailable - sleeping for 1 second"
  sleep 1
done

>&2 echo "MySQL is up - executing command"
exec $cmd
```

Then I edited the `docker-compose.test.yml` as shown below:

```yaml
version: '3.4'

services:
  app:
    image: gcr.io/${PROJECT_ID}/<REDACTED>/test:${SHORT_SHA}
    command: ["./scripts/wait-for-mysql.sh", "&&", "bundle", "exec", "rails", "t"]
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      - TEST_DATABASE_URL=mysql2://root@db/sales_test
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7.24
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=true
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=<REDACTED>

networks:
  default:
      external:
          name: cloudbuild
```